# Runnable is getting blocked, why is this happening? ANDROID

Tags: android, multithreading

I am making an inhouse navigation application with google glass. I am sending orientation data from the google glass to the android phone true WIFI (SOCKETS). My code is running fine and ok, but after about 25 seconds the receiving thread (on the phone) stops for 5 seconds and then continues, this is very annoying.

I tested this by closing the connection (when i see the thread becoming unresponsive) and it takes 5 seconds for the debugger to hit the breakpoint that i set in the application (obviously this is the thread that is causing the problem)

The weird thing is that the UI thread is still responsive i can move every object in the activity, it is just the specific thread containing the connection (Socket) that is getting blocked. I will post the code (i suspect memory leak) so that maybe someone can give me a indication why this could be happening, any advice is welcome.

CHANGED CODE AFTER COMMENT:

```
public class GlassOrientationSocket implements Runnable {
private final static int PORT = 6604;
private static Socket mClientSocket;
private static String mResult;
private static Handler handler = null;
private static boolean threadIsRunning;
private static BufferedReader inputReader;

public GlassOrientationSocket(Handler handler) {
    this.handler = handler;
    this.threadIsRunning = true;
}
public void terminateThread() {this.threadIsRunning = false;}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public  void run() {
    //Replace this with ip-address of android server (aka Google glass) // put ip on NFC TAG for easier configuration
    String ServerIP = SECRET;
    //port should be same as ServerSocketActivity
    try {
        mClientSocket = new Socket(serverIP, PORT);
        inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mClientSocket.getInputStream()));
        int angleCutter;
        int orientationCutter;
        float[] results = new float[2];

        while(threadIsRunning)
        {
            if (((mResult = inputReader.readLine()) != null)) {
                angleCutter = mResult.indexOf("|", 0);
                orientationCutter = mResult.indexOf("|", angleCutter + 1);
                results[0] = Float.valueOf(mResult.substring(0, angleCutter));
                results[1] = Float.valueOf(mResult.substring(angleCutter + 1, orientationCutter));
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.arg1 = 1;
                msg.obj = results;
                handler.sendMessage(msg);
            } else {
                if (mClientSocket != null) mClientSocket.close();
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.arg1 = 2;
                handler.sendMessage(msg);
                threadIsRunning = false;
            }
        }

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }}
```

////

```
public class CompassMonitor {

static protected ArrayList<CompassListener> listeners=new ArrayList<CompassListener>();

static protected GlassOrientationSocket monitor=null;

private static Handler msgHandler = new Handler();
private static CompassListener orientationListener;
private static float[] dataReturned = new float[2];

static public synchronized void registerListener(Context context,CompassListener listener){
    if(listeners.size()==0){
        orientationListener = listener;
        monitor=new GlassOrientationSocket(msgHandler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                switch (msg.arg1) {
                    case 1:
                        dataReturned = (float[])msg.obj;
                        notifyListeners(dataReturned[0],dataReturned[1],"Useless Parameter");
                    break;
                    case 2:
                        unregisterListener(orientationListener);
                        monitor.terminateThread();
                }

            }
        });
        Thread t = new Thread(monitor);
        t.start();
    }
    listeners.add(listener);
}

static synchronized public void unregisterListener(CompassListener listener){
    if (listeners != null && listener != null)
        listeners.remove(listener);
}

static synchronized protected void notifyListeners(float azimuth,float angle, String direction){
    for(CompassListener l:listeners){
        try{
            l.onCompassChanged(azimuth,angle,direction);
        }catch(Exception ex){}
    }
}}
```

Comment: how many (more or less) Messages do you send per second?

Comment: It's about 4 messages a second. I know it would be better to create message object outside of the Thread loop, but that doesn't work. I have not been able to get this code to work with message object recycled. (aka dont create new message everytime i want to send one)

Comment: hmm i thought you send thousands of them per second... yet still use Message.obtain(Handler, int, Object) or Handler.obtainMessage(int, Object) where Object is for example float[] what decreases the memory usage (instead of Bundle)

Comment: I did this, and changed the code to run at 20 times a second. The same thing still happens. it runs perfectly for about 20 seconds, then gets blocked for 3 seconds.... sigh. I can make a video with the glass showing the problem. Would this help you in helping me ?

Comment: if it is a glass specific problem then sorry but i have zero experience with it... can you find where its blocked? when reading the socket? try some Log.d before readLine and after it

Comment: This code is not running on the glass, this is the client code running on a Galaxy Note 3, the server runs on glass and that thread is running fine (not getting blocked at all). I will try and investigate some more.